# Foreign Key Relationships with Entity Framework Code First (EntityData Issue)

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have two entity models, an Account and User and I am having difficulties implement foreign keys in the dependant model (User). As I am developing an Azure Mobile Service app I need to use the Entity Data interface which provides an 'Id' key field by default.

```
public class Account : EntityData
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsBusiness { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
}

public class User : EntityData
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=2), ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

My issue occurs when I specify I want to find 'AccountId' Entity Framework interprets it as 'Account' table, 'Id' column.

Output from Code Migrations:-

> User_Account_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'User_Account_Source' in relationship 'User_Account'. Because the
>   Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound
>   of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
>   User_Account_Target_User_Account_Source: : The types of all properties
>   in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as
>   the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
>   property 'AccountId' on entity 'User' does not match the type of
>   property 'Id' on entity 'Account' in the referential constraint
>   'User_Account'.

Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why does `User` have a compound primary key? Shouldn't `Id` be enough?

Comment: I don't want to use the GUID Id field generated by EntityData, instead using my own (UserId and AccountId). Trying to make my Key primary but I have to order it due to the EntityData Id key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why EF understands it is one-to-many relationship instead one-to-one is because you are composing your PKs with the `Id` property, wich is not a FK.In **one-to-one** relationships one end must be **principal** and second end must be **dependent**. **Principal end** is the one which will be inserted first and which can exist without the dependent one. **Dependent end** is the one which must be inserted after the principal because it has foreign key to the principal. When configuring one-to-one relationships, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the foreign key, otherwise EF doesn't see it as one-to-one relation.

```
public class Account
{
   [Key]
   public int  Id  { get; set; }

   public virtual User User{ get; set; }
}

public class User
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Account")]
   public int  AccountId { get; set; }

   public virtual Account Account{ get; set; } 
}
```

If you think about that, it makes sense,otherwise, the below records could happen:

```
Accounts
Id 
11111111
22222222

Users
Id       AccountId
12rr      11111111
22tt      11111111
```

Comment: I can't use `Id` though because that property is already defined in the Base Class `EntityData` - which I need to inherit from for controllers for Web Apis

Comment: see this http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/